# What is uniqueidentifier type?

Tags: database-design, terminology

In SQL server there is a type uniqueidentifier? What is this? What does it do? What is the difference between this and using primary key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [GUID column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx). <strike>This means that every time you insert a row into this table SQL Server will generate a new [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) and put it into this column</strike>. This ensures that the value is unique and not only on this computer but over all the computers on the world.

---

UPDATE:

As pointed out by @tdammers in the comments section new GUIDs are not automatically generated when inserting rows but this effect could be achieved by defining [`newid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) as default value for the column.

Comment: It doesn't automatically generate one unless you tell it to. You can set the default for a GUID column to `newid()` to automatically generate a new GUID upon insertion.

Comment: @tdammers, yes very good remark. I will update my answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

A `uniqueidentifier` is the SQL Server name for a `GUID` (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier). The central idea is that a GUID is large enough and has enough entropy to make collisions of two randomly generated GUIDs extremely unlikely. To further reduce the likelyhood of collisions, most GUID generators include some value that uniquely identifies the host in the hashing process, such as the primary NIC's MAC address, and maintain a machine-wide counter to avoid collisions between GUIDs generated on the same machine.

In SQL Server, a `uniqueidentifier` is just another data type, like `int`, `varchar`, etc., but its characteristics make it suitable as a primary key. It is much larger than a typical auto-increment integer, but it makes replication and migration much easier - data from two previously unrelated databases will not produce collisions on the primary keys if you use GUIDs, because each GUID is (conceptually) globally unique. With auto-incrementing primary keys, you will certainly get overlaps, because both tables once started at 1, and modifying the primary key values means you also have to modify any foreign key values referencing this record. It can be done, but it's much harder than simply using GUIDs.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned already, and others also pointed out - the GUID / `uniqueidentifier` data type in SQL Server at first appears to be a great candidate for primary key - let me warn you about some problems it has down the road that you might regret later on:

You need to keep apart the **primary key** which is a logical construct - it uniquely identifies your rows, it has to be unique and stable and NOT NULL. A GUID works well for a primary key, too - since it's guaranteed to be unique. A GUID as your primary key is a good choice if you use SQL Server replication, since in that case, you need an uniquely identifying GUID column anyway.

The **clustering key** in SQL Server is a physical construct is used for the physical ordering of the data, and is a lot more difficult to get right. Typically, the Queen of Indexing on SQL Server, Kimberly Tripp, also requires a good clustering key to be uniqe, stable, as narrow as possible, and ideally ever-increasing (which a INT IDENTITY is).

See her articles on indexing here:

- [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
- [The Clustered Index Debate Continues...](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx)
- [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate..........again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx)

and also see Jimmy Nilsson's [The Cost of GUIDs as Primary Key](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25862)

A GUID is a **horribly bad choice** for a clustering key, since it's wide, totally random, and thus leads to bad index fragmentation and poor performance. Also, the clustering key row(s) is also stored in each and every entry of each and every non-clustered (additional) index, so you really want to keep it small - GUID is 16 byte vs. INT is 4 byte, and with several non-clustered indices and several million rows, this makes a HUGE difference.

In SQL Server, your primary key is by default your clustering key - but it doesn't have to be. You can easily use a GUID as your NON-Clustered primary key, and an INT IDENTITY as your clustering key - it just takes a bit of being aware of it.